# How do I display an alternate message if an object does not exist in my array? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

The object of this application is to translate between english and spanish words.
(Checks text input against all array values to see if it's there and then compares that index to the second array, and displays the parallel value).

That part is working.  If the word entered does not exist in the array, I am supposed to have a message like 'No translation available' display in the label. My problem is, I can either get the message to display for nothing or everything - rather than just when it is supposed to.

```
#import "TranslatorViewController.h"

@interface TranslatorViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)translate:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *english;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *spanish;

@end


@implementation TranslatorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
_textField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//make the keyboard go away
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

{[textField resignFirstResponder];}
return YES;
}


- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {     self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]; if(self) {     // Add your custom init code here

self.english = @[@"phone",
                 @"dog",
                 @"sad",
                 @"happy",
                 @"crocodile"];
self.spanish = @[@"telefono",
                 @"perro",
                 @"triste",
                 @"felize",
                 @"cocodrilo"];
}  return self; }



- (IBAction)translate:(id)sender {


//loop through the array
NSString *englishWord = self.textField.text;

for (int index=0; index<[self.english count]; index++)
    if([[self.english objectAtIndex:index]
    isEqualToString:englishWord])

    //retrieve the accompanying spanish word if english word exists in the array

{NSString *spanishWord = [self.spanish objectAtIndex:index];
    //and display it in the label
    self.label.text = spanishWord;}

   //Need code to display 'no translation' if word was not found.

}



@end
```

Comment: As an aside, you might consider using an `NSDictionary` to map between the English and Spanish words. The code will be cleaner + it'll be more performant (won't matter for 4 items, but it's a good habit to be using a dictionary for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is probably to set the label's text field to "No translation" *before* entering the loop. If no match is found, the label will never be re-set to anything else.

There are lots of other ways to structure logic to give you this result. I might tighten up that last loop of code by doing this instead:

```
NSString * englishWord = self.textField.text;

NSUInteger spanishWordIndex = [self.english indexOfObject:englishWord];
if (spanishWordIndex == NSNotFound) {
    self.label.text = @"No translation";
} else {
    self.label.text = self.spanish[spanishWordIndex];
}
```

Comment: But then if for example I put in a word that IS there, and then tried to put in one that isn't, would it revert back to the default?

Comment: @Kate: I'm not certain of exactly what you mean, but you can think of it this way-- at the end of the event loop, the last thing you set the label to will be what shows up on the screen (until the next time you change it). So every time your `translate` action is invoked, it will step through this logic, and set it to either the result or the "no translation" placeholder.

Comment: That code makes 'no translation show up for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an NSDictionary?

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {     
     self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]; 
     if(self) {     // Add your custom init code here

        self.translationDict = @{@"phone":@"telefono",
                 @"dog":@"perro",
                 @"sad": @"triste",
                 @"happy": @"felize",
                 @"crocodile": @"cocodrilo"]; // self.translationDict is an NSDictionary

     }  
     return self; 

 }


 - (IBAction)translate:(id)sender {
      NSString *englishWord = self.textField.text;
      NSString *spanishWord=self.translationDict[englishWord];
      if (spanishWord == nil) {
         spanishWord="No Translation";
      }
      self.label.text=spanishWord;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted the answer to include your entire code. You should be able to just copy paste into your code.

```
- (IBAction)translate:(id)sender {

    NSString *englishWord = self.textField.text;
    NSString *spanishWord = @"No translation found.";

    for (int index=0; index<[self.english count]; index++)
    {
        if([[self.english objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToString:englishWord])
        {
            //retrieve the accompanying spanish word if english word exists in the array
            spanishWord = [self.spanish objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }

    self.label.text = spanishWord;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put

self.label.text = @"No translation available";

before the if statement which is I believe what Ben Zotto was trying to say! I just wasn't sure how to actually do it at first. 
I'm a newb with this stuff.

But that did what I needed it to.

Thanks all!

Comment: That is not going to work, since it will show the 'No Translation available' message on subsequent loops even if you do have a translation. Example: the code enters into the loop, it sets the label to No Translation available, checks if there is one. if it finds one it will set the translation correctly. Then it will look to the next element in the array, set the label to 'No translation available', erasing your translation. setting it before the for loop is the one that should have worked.